# javascript of recaptcha is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, lightbox

please help...

when i use the code below used in the form it does not open the form at all in the lightbox / fancybox. but when i remove it it works.

**Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Recaptcha.create("6Ld5necSAAAAAMNoodwSDBwEWAQi3Yd3VHHSsZnr",
    "recaptcha",
    {
      theme: "red",
      callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
    }
  );
</script>
```

**Button is like this:**

```
<li class="email gradient_button"><a href="forms/friends.php?recaptcha" class="fancybox_div">Email to a Friend</a></li>
```

**and the form is like this:**

```
<form name="email_friend" method="post" class="ajax_form">
    <table>
        <tr><td>Name: </td> <td> <input type="text" name="name"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Email: </td> <td> <input type="text" name="email"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Friends Email: </td> <td> <input type="text" name="friends_email"></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2">Message:<br>
            <textarea name="message" class="fancybox_textarea"></textarea></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan='2'><br><div id='recaptcha'></div></td></tr>        <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="pull-left"></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

**The full file of form looks like this:**

```
<h3>Email to a Friend</h3>

<form name="email_friend" method="post" class="ajax_form">
    <table>
        <tr><td>Name: </td> <td> <input type="text" name="name"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Email: </td> <td> <input type="text" name="email"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Friends Email: </td> <td> <input type="text" name="friends_email"></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2">Message:<br>
            <textarea name="message" class="fancybox_textarea"></textarea></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan='2'><br><div id='recaptcha'></div></td></tr>        <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="pull-left"></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
Recaptcha.create("6Ld5necSAAAAAMNoodwSDBwEWAQi3Yd3VHHSsZnr",
    "recaptcha",
    {
      theme: "red",
      callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
    }
  );
</script>
```

when i remove the javascript part it opens the form in lightbox / fancybox but with this code it does not open anything.

can you please tell me the issue???

Comment: Have you checked your console? Is it returning an error?

Comment: @Mouser please help me i do not understand this actually i got this template from internet and what is the issue i can not understand if u can help me out on this issue ... if you need any file to check i can provide